# App crashing when I submit form using `flow_builder`

Tags: flutter

I'm building a simple app using `flow_builder` to control the flow of navigation. When I submit the form, I create a copy of the form data and then submit it using a button. the problem is that the screen goes blank and I have to restart the app to get it to work again. The data *is* going through, as we can see the data on the server. I suspect the way I'm calling the async is the issue, but I'll put the dio call in here too. The button looks like this:

```
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 410),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                minimumSize: const Size(200, 65),
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                _continuePressed();
                var value = await _finalOffer.submit();
              },
              child: Text('Next', style: headerLabels),
            ),
          ),
```

The dio call looks like this:

```
Future<Response> sendPayload(String url, Map<String, dynamic> payload) async {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  dio.options.headers.addAll({
    'X-Corporate-IDs': 'SuperSecret',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  });
  var response = await dio.post(url, data: payload);
  return response;
}
```

There are additional pages of text to be displayed after the form is submitted.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!